# Cклонение фамилии Штонда

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Здравствуйте!

Хотела уточнить: склоняется ли фамилия Штонда, принадлежащая женщине.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Мужские и женские фамилии и личные имена, оканчивающиеся на -а, -я неударное, склоняются независимо от их языковой принадлежности (в том числе и к грузинскому, японскому, финскому языкам).

Л. П. Калакуцкая, "Фамилии. Имена. Отчества. Написание и склонение", М., 1994.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!!!

Answer (score 0):

Нет, женские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на А, не склоняются.

Comment: и где это прописано? укажите пожалуйста ссылку на учебник/правило или другой источник.

Comment: прошу указать источник, так как на сайте Грамота.ру указано правило: 
13.1.11.
Все фамилии, кончающиеся на неударное а после согласных, склоняются по первому склонению: Рибера — Риберы, Рибере, Риберу, Риберой, Сенека — Сенеки и т.д.; так же склоняются Кафка, Спиноза, Сметана, Петрарка, Куросава, Глинка, Дейнека, Гулыга, Олеша, Нагнибеда, Окуджава и др. Все такие фамилии, независимо от происхождения, являются морфологически членимыми в русском языке, т. е. в них выделяется окончание -а.

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что на -я тоже подходит под это правило однозначно. Попробуйте просклонять грузинскую фамилию Гурцкая(Диана Гурцкая, Эдуард Гурцкая)или Шенгелая(Ариадна Шенгелая, Николай Шенгелая). Как-то неладно выходит...

Comment: Неладно - это как?
Диана Гурцкая, Дианы Гурцкаи, Диане Гурцкае, Диану Гурцкаю, Дианой Гурцкаей, (о) Диане Гурцкае.
Тренируйтесь, все получится. А когда научитесь, попробуйте ещё во множественном числе. ;) Диана и Эдуард Гурцкаи... Как Петя и Маша Ивановы.

Comment: Мое представление о русском языке отказывается склонять подобные грузинские(абхазские) фамилии, а еще Гагуа,Гулиа и подобные. С Окуджавой, кстати, у меня все в порядке. Но НИКОГДА не встречал что-либо подобное: "изобретенное Нурбеем Гулией", и у самого язык не поворачивается, наверное, это как раз "неправильное" правило, язык сопротивляется.

Comment: Наверное, проще избегать склонения подобных фамилий, обозначая субъект описания другими словами: "профессором", "изобретателем", "инженером" и т.п.